# wildcard on column name in select projection

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two table like this:

```
Table1 : xA, yA, zA, xB, yB, zB
Table2 : x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2
```

I want to insert data from `Table1` to `Table2` such as all `*B` columns data goes to `*1` columns respectively and all `*A`s to `*1`s in the same way.

I tried this query:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT xB, yB, zB, xA, yA, zA FROM Table1
```

but considering maintainability, is there any other solution without using name of columns explicitly? Suppose I need to add new columns w1, w2, wA, wB. In this case I must change the query.

Comment: You will have to use dynamic SQL, it's your only way. You can have a temporary table with mappings (A - 1, B - 2) and create the insert statement by looping each relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do what you want uses dynamic SQL.  I'm not sure if that is more maintainable.

However in the interest of maintainability, you should list all the columns explicitly:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2)
     SELECT xB, yB, zB, xA, yA, zA
     FROM Table1;
```

Comment: thx @Gordon. but suppose I need to add new columns w1, w2, wA, wB. In this case I must change the query

Comment: @TaherKhorshidi . . . Adding columns to a table should be something that is very rarely needed.  I would question your data model if you are planning for such changes.

Answer (score 0):

As you are having order of columns of Table1 mapping to different order of columns of Table2. I would suggest you to create a mapping table `Table1Table2Mapping`.

```
+--------------+ --------------+
| Table1Column | Table2Column  | 
+--------------+ --------------+
|x1            | xB            |
|y1            | yB            |
|z1            | zB            |
|x2            | xA            |
|y2            | yA            |
|z2            | zA            |
+--------------+----------------+
```

Generate dynamic SQL by querying these two columns.